# Determing the difference between no solutions and infinite with NumPy / LinAlg

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy, linear-algebra

I have code that inputs 12 coefficient variables and using linalg from numpy to determine the solution. If there is zero solutions or infinite, the det(A) returns 0. How do I differentiate between none and infinite solutions in my elif line?

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from scipy.linalg import solve


a = float(input("Enter coefficient a: "))
b = float(input("Enter coefficient b: "))
c = float(input("Enter coefficient c: "))
d = float(input("Enter coefficient d: "))
e = float(input("Enter coefficient e: "))
f = float(input("Enter coefficient f: "))
g = float(input("Enter coefficient g: "))
h = float(input("Enter coefficient h: "))
i = float(input("Enter coefficient i: "))
j = float(input("Enter coefficient j: "))
k = float(input("Enter coefficient k: "))
l = float(input("Enter coefficient l: "))

A = np.array([[a, b, c],
              [e, f, g],
              [i, j, k]])
b = np.array([d, h, l])


if (np.linalg.det(A)) != 0:
    print(np.linalg.solve(A, b))
elif (np.linalg.det(A)) == 0:
        print("Infinite or no solutions")
```

Comment: It isn't possible to handle degenerate cases like this reliably in floating point. I suggest using SymPy for exact arithmetic with rational numbers rather than floats.

Answer (score 0):

Given the linear system Ax = B and the augmented matrix (A|B) :
(a) If rank(A) = rank(A|B) < the number of rows in x, then the system has infinitely solutions.
(b) If rank(A) < rank(A|B), then the system is inconsistent.

You may use this in the elif condition (Ref: numpy.linalg.[matrix_rank](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_rank.html))